# Android webview change dynamically change cache mode

Tags: android, caching, android-webview, offline-caching, webviewclient

My project is an app that contains a webview that should run offline using offline cache. What I want to happen is for it to set cachemode to load_default when connection to the site throws response code of 200, and set cachemode to load_cache_else_network if it doesn't.

And when touched a link, meaning loading another url, it runs the same process of checking for response code and setting cachemode.

But the problem is that it jumps right into onReceivedError(), which was only planned to happen if cache wasn't saved. onReceivedError contains loading a page within the app, and that's how I know that the process jumps right into it.

Any good advices please?

And, additional question, what is a good way to check if cache is saved?